# Print page of information in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm building an application that takes information I pull from a web service and builds it into a simple looking page to print out. Is their a way to make some kind of layout so i can just fill in the blanks with my data in the appropriate places and print. Specifically I want to be able to print a page that includes multiple images and text arranged in a specific manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Crystal Report is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's Crystal Report and also RDLC that you can use.